# Unable to read file with Scanner in Java

Tags: java, readfile

I'm attempting to pass a File object to the Scanner constructor.

```
File file = new File("in.txt");
try{
   Scanner fileReader = new Scanner(file);
}
catch(Exception exp){
   System.out.println(exp.getMessage());
}
```

I have an in.txt in the root of the project, src and bin directories in case I'm getting the location wrong. I have tried giving absolute paths as well. This line

```
Scanner fileReader = new Scanner(file);
```

always fails. Execution jumps to the end of main. If I misspell the name of the file, I get a FileNotFoundException. I'm on an Ubuntu 12.10 Java 1.7 with OpenJDK

Comment: so you mean to say not able to access with asbolute path too

Comment: Either you get an exception, or you don't. But execution doesn't jump to the end of a method without reason. What happens precisely. ANd what's the rest of the code? Also, you're hiding the type of the exception by catching Exception and not displaying the exception stacktrace. Replace the catch block by `catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }` or even better, don't catch the exception at all, and add a throws clause to the method.

Comment: try file.exists() and show what it returns ?

Comment: give full path of File[eg: **File("/tmp/in.txt")** or **File("D:\\in.txt")**] and also use **file.exists()**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am running on linux and this is how you need to do it

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Testing {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        Scanner s = null;
        try {
            //notice the path is fully qualified path
            s = new Scanner(new File("/tmp/one.txt"));
            while (s.hasNext()) {
                System.out.println(s.next());
            }
        } finally {
            if (s != null) {
                s.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

here is the result :
[image]

[source from Java Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you do: `File file = new File("in.txt");` in your java program
(let's assume it is named Program.java) then the file `in.txt` should
be in the working directory of your program at runtime. So if you
run your program like this:

`java Program`

or

`java package1.package2.Program`

and you are in `/test1/test2/` when running this command,
then the file `in.txt` needs to be in `/test1/test2/`.